# Select/Update cause long sql wait times

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, database-deadlocks

I'm trying to understand exactly what is happening here. I realize select/update combinations can cause deadlocks - in this case a longggg wait.

The scenario is this
Query A is a select statement that uses three indexes
(very simplified)

```
select * from ProblemTable Where Plan_Id=@planId and 
    Date_entered Between @startDate and @endDate and nabp=@nabp
```

Indexes are all Non Clustered :

1. Plan_Id
2. Date_Entered
3. Plan_Id, nabp

All have 'output' of ProblemTable.Unique_Id

Query B is an update statement that uses two indexes

Indexes are:

1. Non Clustered Date_Entered ASC, Source ASC, DataStartOffset ASC
2. Clustered Index on Unique_Id used on the results of Index 1's index search.

Update query:

```
Update ProblemTable Set ProcessingTime=@processingTime 
Where dateadd(dd, -datediff(dd, date_entered, 1), 1) = 
dateadd(dd, -datediff(dd, getdate(), 1), 1) 
and DateSource = 'xxyyzz' and DataStartOffset = 93148143
```

I know.. the dateadd is goofy. I didn't write this : )

So this scans a *separate* index than query A but also using Date_Entered.
A long wait keeps occuring because of this situation. A deadlock doesn't seemingly occur, but it can cause a wait time of 5+ minutes where each query normally executes in seconds.

Note that this also occurs on an INSERT into ProblemTable

So - 
I'm guessing the SELECT stmt aquires locks on the rows it finally determines to select based on the NC index searches and the update statement then tries to aquire a lock on the rows returned from its search on the NC index. But why is it just taking a longgggg time then but no deadlock is occuring?

The questions then basically are:

1 Why the long wait time as opposed to a deadlock? 
2. Whats causing this?

Is there enough info available here?

**EDIT 1** Both queries are fairly quick and neither take anywhere near this long. The long time is a result of 'some' unknown locking issue here. There are no other explicit transactions going on.

Comment: I had a similar issue but it was related to reindexing the table and i had a bad switch connection.

Answer (score 0):

A select from a single table typically uses a single index.  If there's multiple indexes available, SQL Server will try to choose the most limiting index, based on statistics it stores automatically.

An update that waits for 5 minutes is not normal.  Try to figure out what's blocking it-- [Adam Machanic's sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com) is a good start.  My usual suspect would be a long-running transaction that is not committed as quickly as it should be.

Comment: The select statement is blocking it, this is what I'm trying to get to the bottom of as to the specifics of 'why' . Select stmts can cause deadlocks with a separate update - so I'd almost expect that here (although I think the index on the select is preventing deadlock) but we're not out of the clear because of these long waits. There are no other transactions - this is the case here thats the issue. We've checked blocked process reports, etc (plus the system doesnt use any long explicit transactions)

Comment: @Adam Tuliper: An update issues an "intent" lock.  When the intent is present, new selects will be blocked, in order to prevent the update from being delayed indefinitely by selects.  The update then waits for all other locks to finish, and proceeds to update the row.

Comment: That makes sense in a normal world ...but in this case how is the select blocking just this update for so long? Each query completes in say.... 2 seconds. We are seeing wait times of five minutes now.

Comment: @Adam Tuliper: For example, the first `select` could be running for 5 minutes, blocking the `intent` lock, and thus all other `selects`.  Have you tried sp_WhoIsActive?  It will probably tell you what's happening right away.

Comment: We have run this - we also run deadlock detector. I think you may be slightly missing the issue though (maybe not!) The first select doesn't run for 5 minutes - of this we're certain. During this 'issue' suddenly the wait times go up by a factor of 100+ - I would almost expect to see a deadlock here had we not ha certain indexes but instead long waits. Something is causing a long wait that otherwise wouldn't run 'long' so Im wondering if there is anything else in lock management that Im missing. The blocking process is the select, however this select _never_ takes that long.

Comment: lets get a bit more advanced here. there is something that I've read happens when a particular index is used during a range search in a select, but then a lock is either upgraded or a new index is used in the update. I'm wondering if that isn't related to this issue - although in that case you usually see a deadlock occur, but in this case its a long wait instead that triggers our deadlock (wait) report.

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT that update statement is going to scan, and the update is probably going to escalate the lock from page to table which will prevent anything else from touching the table while that lock is held.

We should meet as I'm in the SoCal area.  Might I recommend that you swing by the SQL Saturday in Orange County next month? https://www.sqlsaturday.com/389/eventhome.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use Sql Profiler for the root cause of this issue.
```

Are you using triggers for this table?

You can use **No Locks** for the select statement

Comment: thats somewhat of a generic answer : ) We're aware of the tools, and we've done some fairly advanced analysis on this and have reports on the waiting processes and the blocking processes. We're aware of which two queries are causing the issue. Using 'no lock' can be quite dangerous for many reasons - all available on many blogs and stack overflow question. Duplicate reads, dirty reads, skipped pages, etc. are a few of the reasons not to use no lock. We want to understand the exact and potentially fix it rather than patch it with a dirty read.